# how to remove horizental scroll in html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a simple web page template.my problem is that, my web page has a horizontal scroll. But I want remove it. This is my code:

```
 <html lang="FA">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <section class="bg-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                <h2 class="logo-text d-inline-block p-4 ps-0">My logo text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="bg-secondary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center" style="height: 800px;">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <div class="search-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-field w-50" placeholder="search">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="bg-yellow">
        <div class="container">
          
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is screen shot of result:

[image: this is my result:]

Any solution?

Comment: have you tried setting the body css to `overflow-x: hidden`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow: hidden;` is fine to use. But I suggest looking at your markup. Bootstrap adds a `margin-left` & `margin-right` to the `row` class. In this case `margin-right` is the culprit.

[image: Bootstrap Row Class]

Try it like this:

**Rearranged Markup:**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="">
        <h2 class="logo-text d-inline-block p-4 ps-0">My logo text</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center" style="height: 800px;">
      <div class="search-container">
        <div class="search-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control search-field w-50" placeholder="search">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer class="bg-yellow">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</footer>
```

**Original Markup:**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="">
      <h2 class="logo-text d-inline-block p-4 ps-0">My logo text</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center" style="height: 800px;">
      <div class="search-container">
        <div class="search-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control search-field w-50" placeholder="search">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer class="bg-yellow">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: yes,it's work for all page.tank you

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the body css using the overflow-x property for horizontal scrollbars like this:

```
.body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the class="row" div inside container div

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="">
            <h2 class="logo-text d-inline-block p-4 ps-0">My logo text</h2>
        </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```